# Count number of lists within a nested list that is not separated

Tags: python, list, nested, counting

So I have a giant list, that has a number of lists nested within it, and I want to get a count of the number of lists that are within this big outer list. The problem is that these lists aren't separated by anything, the look like this:

```
[[list1][list2][list3][list4]]
```

Please help!

Comment: I tried len it gives me 1. because the sub-lists aren't separated by commas of \n or \r and stuff Python thinks that the whole outer list has only one sub-list within it.

Comment: Is what you have a string? I don't think it is a list.

Comment: what is `type(nested_list[0])`?

Comment: type(nested_list) is a str! oops sorry for the mistake on the post!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments, it looks like your list looks something like

```
nested = ['[a][b][c][d]']
```

(So `len(nested)=1`, and `type(nested_list[0])` is a `str`)

To count the number of "lists", you can do:

```
len(nested[0].split(']['))
```

Comment: +1 from me, for having a better crystal ball or scrying glass than me. How did you guess the actual input?

Comment: how can I sort this huge outer list with nested lists that have one specific value and group those together? using itertools?

Answer (score 0):

Supposing that your data is a string as it cannot possibly be a list, you can try the following iff the list is not nested more deeply and does not contain strings containing `][`:

```
x = '[[list1][list2][list3][list4]]'
print (len (x.split ('][') ) )
>>> 4
```

Comment: I get error as 
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'

Answer (score 0):

Here are my assumptions, based on your description:

- What you have is a string that looks *almost* like a list
- Each item in this *'pseudo-list'* is another *'pseudo-list'*
- The *'pseudo-list'* might be nested to any level
- You want to count these *'pseudo-list'*

Here is what I have in mind:

- I call the first list a level-1 list
- We are interested to find out how many level-2 lists there are

Code:

```
import collections

li = '[[list1][list2][list3][list4]]'
counter = collections.Counter()
level = 0
for c in li:
    if c == '[':
        level += 1
        counter.update([level])
    elif c == ']':
        level -= 1

# We are interested in number of second-level lists
print 'List length:', counter[2]
```

Output:

```
List length: 4
```

This code works for arbitrarily nested lists, such as:

```
li = '[[1][2][3][4[a][b][c][d]]]'
```

Answer (score 0):

use a recursive function to walk the nested list tree

```
  nested_list = [[['list 1'],['list 5']],['list2'],['list3'],['list4'],{'hello':'world'}]

 def countLists(nested_list):
   #print(nested_list)
   if len(nested_list)==1 & isinstance(nested_list,list):
        #print("return")
        return 1

    count=0
    for alist in nested_list:
         if isinstance(alist, list):
            retCount=countLists(alist)
            count+=retCount
            #print(alist)
    return count
        
countLists(nested_list)
```

output:
5